# Android - How to cast Object [] to File []

Tags: java, android, file, object

I'm creating an app in android! I'm trying to pass File[] from my Main Activity class using this line of code:

```
File[] listFile;
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Eye Spy");
   if (file.isDirectory()) {
       listFile = (File[]) file.listFiles();
   }
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("images", listFile);
```

to my MapsActivity using this line of code:

```
listFile = (File[]) getIntent().getExtras().get("images");
```

But when I run the app, it displays an error message saying:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pathnrdo.eyespy1/com.example.pathnrdo.eyespy1.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.io.File[]

What seems to be the problem? And how can i fix it? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: You can't put an `Object[]` array into a `Bundle`.  You will need to find some other way of passing your array of files to another Activity.

Answer (score 3):

`file.listFiles()` already return a File[],you don't need to cast again.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah! But I need to pass it to another activity.

Comment: class File also implements Serializable,just an Intent is OK.But i think that's something you can do on every activity,so why don't you get your listFile on your MapActivity

Answer (score 2):

Okay! I already solved my problem! I just implemented these codes to my MapsActivity so that I don't have to pass it from activity to activity:

```
File[] listFile;
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Eye Spy");
   if (file.isDirectory()) {
       listFile = (File[]) file.listFiles();
   }
```

Comment: This is the way to go, IMO.  It would appear to be non trivial to create a custom class implementing `Parceable` just so you can pass files from one activity to another.  Just use the files in one activity, and close them.  If you really need them again, then open in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that `getIntent().getExtras().get("*KEY*");` returns an Object and you cannot simply cast an Object[] to a File[].

So what you want do is to cast every single Object in the the Object-Array to File.

As an example you can do something like this:

```
final Object[] potentialFiles = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("*KEY*");
List<File> list = new LinkedList<>();

Objects.requireNonNull(potentialFiles);
for (final Object o : potentialFiles) {
    if (o instanceof File) {
        list.add((File) o);
    }
}

File[] files = list.toArray(new File[]{});
```

Or you can simply put the parentFile (the directory of all files) into the Extras.
Then you can extract all files via:

```
//First Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("*KEY*", parentFile);
startActivity(intent);

//Second Actitiy
File parentFile = (File) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("*KEY*");
File[] files = parentFile.listFiles();
```